# How to use INotifyPropertyChanged on a property in a class within a class..?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

My issue seems to be "scope", though I'm not certain that's the right terminology.  I want to notify a read-only list to re-evaluate itself when a property within a custom object is set.  I believe it is simply not aware of it's existence. Maybe there is an easy way around this I cannot think of, but I'm drawing a blank.

I find this hard to put into words, so here's simplified code with my comments on what I expect to happen.

**Properties within object in which I am databinding to:**

```
private CvarAspectRatios _aspectRatio = new CvarAspectRatios("none", GetRatio());
public CvarAspectRatios AspectRatio
{
    get { return _aspectRatio; }
    set
    {                                                 // This setter never gets hit since I bind to this 
        if (value != null)                            // object's 'Value' property now.
        {
            _aspectRatio = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AspectRatio");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ResolutionList");  // I want to inform ResolutionList
        }                                             // that it needs to repopulate based
    }                                                 // on this property: AspectRatio
}

private ResolutionCollection _resolutionList = ResolutionCollection.GetResolutionCollection();
public ResolutionCollection ResolutionList
{
   get 
   {
       ResolutionCollection list = new ResolutionCollection();
       if (AspectRatio != null && AspectRatio.Value != null)
       {
           foreach (Resolutions res in _resolutionList.Where(i => i.Compatibility == AspectRatio.Value.Compatibility))
           {
               list.Add(res);
           }
           return list;
       }
       return _resolutionList;
   }
}
```

**CvarAspectRatios Class:**

```
public class CVarAspectRatios : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _defaultValue;
    public string DefaultValue
    {
        get { return _defaultValue; }
        set { _defaultValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DefaultValue"); }
    }

    private AspectRatios _value;
    public AspectRatios Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set 
        { 
            _value = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ResolutionList");  // This value gets set, and I'd like for ResolutionList to update
        }                                             // but it cannot find ResolutionList. No errors or anything. Just
    }                                                 // no update.

    public AspectRatios() { }

    public AspectRatios(string defaultValue, AspectRatios val)
    {
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        Value = val;
    }

    // Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged snipped out here
}
```

What do you folks think?  If you'd like a sample application I can whip one up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since CVarAspectRatios implements INotifyPropertyChanged, you can have the viewmodel class subscribe to the PropertyChanged event for the AspectRatio.

```
public class YourViewModel 
{
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        AspectRatio.PropertyChanged += AspectRatio_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void AspectRatio_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Value")
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ResolutionList");
    }        
}
```

Just bear in mind that if you discard that AspectRatio object (if the object reference changes and not just the value property of that object), you should unsubscribe from the event on the discarded one.

Comment: When I do this while bound to a DataGridView, I get an InvalidOperationException.

`BindingSource cannot be its own data source. Do not set the DataSource and DataMember properties to values that refer back to BindingSource.`

Comment: I'm not sure that your error is caused by the above implementation, as nothing is being set.

Answer (score 2):

To just transform your existing code into something which should work:

```
private CvarAspectRatios _aspectRatio; //No field initialization because that would not attach event handler, you could do it though and take care of the handler alone in the ctor
public CvarAspectRatios AspectRatio
{
    get { return _aspectRatio; }
    set
    {
        if (_aspectRatio != value) // WTH @ "value != null"
        {
            _aspectRatio.PropertyChanged -= AspectRatio_PropertyChanged;
            _aspectRatio = value;
            _aspectRatio.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(AspectRatio_PropertyChanged);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AspectRatio");
        }
    }
}

void AspectRatio_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Value")
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ResolutionList");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote it (should have copy/pasted), I did not mean to write value != null, Ha! Your answer is essentially the same as the other guy's. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Well, this is a common thing and it's not like i copied him/her. I actually thought of this before any answers were posted but i couldn't get this coded in time due to a computer restart. You're welcome.

Comment: Indeed you appeared to post simultaneously. Just explaining why it was not marked as accepted.

Comment: Indeed, this is a common pattern to handle the 'parent' viewmodel monitoring the 'children' for changes that require the 'parent' to update some value. H.B.'s solution does correctly illustrate what I added as a warning--you need to unsubscribe from the event if you swap out the AspectRatio.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you factor out re-populating `ResolutionList` into a separate private method which gets called from the setter of `AspectRatios`?

Comment: I believe this would work, though a bit more complicated than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If a list needs to update based on a changed property, the list (or a list manager object, for better encapsulation) would normally need to subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of the object hosting the property.  If the list is itself a property of the same object, as in this case, it would be simpler and leaner for the property's setter to call a method that updates the list.